# Indicate to Rails controller which view called action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial

I have two views which commit a similar controller create action, allowing the user to "Track" a product. Upon clicking the "Track" button, each view submits an AJAX request via remote: true attribute, and the javascript response should re-render the corresponding partial that called it. How can I indicate to my create.js.haml script which view called the action and then respond accordingly?

Code:

Partial #1

```
- if current_user.present? && current_user.tracked_products.include?( @media )
    %a.btn.btn-responsive.btn-thin.btn-color.red-bg{ href: main_app.price_tracker_path( current_user.price_trackers.where( product_id: @media.id  ).first, _method: :delete ), style: 'font-size: 1.2em', data: { method: :delete, remote: true } }
        -# %i.fa.fa-eye-slash
        Stop Tracking
- elsif current_user.present?
    %a.btn.btn-responsive.btn-thin.btn-color.brand-background-color-lavender{ href: main_app.modal_new_price_trackers_path( media_id: @media.slug ), style: 'font-size: 1.2em', data: { toggle: :modal, target: '#new_price_tracker' } }
        -# %i.fa.fa-eye
        Track It
- else
    %a.btn.btn-responsive.btn-thin.btn-color.brand-background-color-lavender{ href: '#', style: 'font-size: 1.2em', data: { toggle: :modal, target: '#login_modal' } }
        -# %i.fa.fa-eye
        Track It
```

Partial #2

```
- if (tracker = current_user.price_trackers.active.where( product: product ).first).present?
    %a.btn-responsive.brand-color-white{ href: main_app.price_tracker_path( tracker, _method: :delete), data: { method: :delete, remote: true} }
        %i.fa.fa-check-circle
        Track
- else
    %a.btn-responsive.brand-color-white{ href: main_app.modal_new_price_trackers_path( media_id: product.slug), data: { toggle: :modal, target: '#new_price_tracker' } }
        Track
```

create.js.haml:

```
if (//some indicator here) {
$('#track-product-'+#{@product.id}).html("#{j render(partial: 'products/track_item_from_card', locals: {product: @product})}");
else {
$('#track-item-button').html("#{j render(partial: 'products/track_item')}"); }
}

$('#new_price_tracker').attr("aria-hidden", "true");
$('#new_price_tracker').attr("style", "display: none;");
```

Comment: Seems like I need something like a hidden_field_tag, but for a link instead of a form

Answer (score 1):

In One view you should put like this.

```
== button_tag 'Save', :value => 'view1', :name => 'commit', :type => 'submit'
```

And in second view

```
== button_tag 'Save', :value => 'view2', :name => 'commit', :type => 'submit'
```

Then in your create action check for `params[:commit]` to identify if it is view1 or view 2.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work with my current link code. Do you mean something like this?

`- else
 %a.btn-responsive.brand-color-white{ href: main_app.modal_new_price_trackers_path( media_id: product.slug), :value => 'view1', data: { toggle: :modal, target: '#new_price_tracker' } }
  Track`